# Concatenate files and update dates and values

Tags: sas

I'm a beginner in SAS.

I have 4 data sets that look like this:

Year_2013

```
   ID         Start         End           Role        Hours        
  0001      01JAN2013    30APR2013        53100        300
  0001      01MAY2013    31DEC2013        50100         3
  0002      01JAN2013    31DEC2013        56100        60
  0003      01JAN2013    31DEC2013        52100       123
  ....      .........    .........        .....       ....
```

Year_2014

```
   ID         Start         End           Role        Hours          
  0001      01JAN2014    31DEC2014        59100        56
  0002      01JAN2014    31NOV2014        56100        12
  0002      01DEC2014    31DEC2014        58100        0
  0003      01JAN2014    31DEC2014        52100       1,34
  0004      01JAN2014    31JUL2014        51100       300
  0004      01AUG2014    31DEC2014        50100       90
  ....      .........    .........        ....        ....
```

Year_2015

```
   ID         Start         End           Role        Hours          
  0001      01JAN2015    31MAR2015        59100        4
  0001      01APR2015    01MAY2015        58100        0
  0001      02MAY2015    31DEC2015        51100       34
  0002      01JAN2015    01APR2015        55101       54
  0002      01MAY2015    01JUN2015        56101        0
  0002      01JUL2015    31DEC2015        56100        0
  0003      01JAN2015    31DEC2015        55107        8
  0004      01JAN2015    31DEC2015        50100       69
  ....      .........    .........        .....
```

Year_2016

```
   ID         Start         End           Role        Hours          
  0001      01JAN2016    30SEP2016        51100        67
  0001      01OCT2016    31DEC2016        52100        0
  0002      01JAN2016    31DEC2015        56101        98
  0003      01JAN2016    31DEC2016        50115        9
  0004      01JAN2016    31JAN2016        51101        7
  0004      01FEB2016    31DEC2016        51106       234
  ....      ..........   .........        ......
```

I need to sum the hours in the "Hours" column only when data are consecutive among years and according to the Role and I need to add a flag when there is a change in Role. The desired output should be:

Years_all

```
   ID         Start         End           Role        Hours            
  0001      01JAN2013    30APR2013        53100        300        
  0001      01MAY2013    31DEC2013        50100         3         
  0001      01JAN2014    31MAR2015        59100        60
  0001      01APR2015    01MAY2015        58100         0
  0001      02MAY2015    30SEP2016        51100        101
  0001      01OCT2016    31DEC2016        52100        0
  0002      01JAN2013    31NOV2014        56100        72
  0002      01DEC2014    31DEC2014        58100        0
  0002      01JAN2015    01APR2015        55101        54
  0002      01MAY2015    01JUN2015        56101        0
  0002      01JUL2015    31DEC2015        56100        0
  0002      01JAN2016    31DEC2015        56101        98
  0003      01JAN2013    31DEC2014        52100       124,34
  0003      01JAN2015    31DEC2015        55107        8
  0003      01JAN2016    31DEC2016        50115        9
  0004      01JAN2014    31JUL2014        50100       300
  0004      01AUG2014    31DEC2015        50100       159
  0004      01JAN2016    31JAN2016        51101        7
  0004      01FEB2016    31DEC2016        51106       234
```

So, for each ID, if the Role remains the same at the next consecutive year (first row of the consecutive year for each ID) then sum "Hours" and adjust the end date otherwise let rows as they are.The sum MUST not be applied inside each single year but only among consecutive years.

For example: in the output, for ID 004 I performed:90+69, i.e.,  31DEC2014 50100  + 31DEC2015 50100 and updated the row in the output to 31DEC2015 because the ID has the same role in the next year (in this case full year).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

- I changed 31NOV2014 to 30NOV2014 for obvious reasons.
- I assume that your posted data is representative of the structure of your actual data.

Code:

```
data year_2013;
input ID (Start End)(:date9.) Role Hours;
format Start End date9.;
datalines;
0001 01JAN2013 30APR2013 53100 300 
0001 01MAY2013 31DEC2013 50100 3   
0002 01JAN2013 31DEC2013 56100 60  
0003 01JAN2013 31DEC2013 52100 123 
;

data year_2014;
input ID (Start End)(:date9.) Role Hours;
format Start End date9.;
datalines;
0001 01JAN2014 31DEC2014 59100 56   
0002 01JAN2014 30NOV2014 56100 12   
0002 01DEC2014 31DEC2014 58100 0    
0003 01JAN2014 31DEC2014 52100 1.34 
0004 01JAN2014 31JUL2014 51100 300  
0004 01AUG2014 31DEC2014 50100 90   
;

data year_2015;
input ID (Start End)(:date9.) Role Hours;
format Start End date9.;
datalines;
0001 01JAN2015 31MAR2015 59100 4  
0001 01APR2015 01MAY2015 58100 0  
0001 02MAY2015 31DEC2015 51100 34 
0002 01JAN2015 01APR2015 55101 54 
0002 01MAY2015 01JUN2015 56101 0  
0002 01JUL2015 31DEC2015 56100 0  
0003 01JAN2015 31DEC2015 55107 8  
0004 01JAN2015 31DEC2015 50100 69 
;

data year_2016;
input ID (Start End)(:date9.) Role Hours;
format Start End date9.;
datalines;
0001 01JAN2016 30SEP2016 51100 67  
0001 01OCT2016 31DEC2016 52100 0   
0002 01JAN2016 31DEC2015 56101 98  
0003 01JAN2016 31DEC2016 50115 9   
0004 01JAN2016 31JAN2016 51101 7   
0004 01FEB2016 31DEC2016 51106 234 
;

data temp;
   set year_:;
run;

proc sort data = temp;
   by ID start;
run;

data want(drop = _:);
   do until (last.role);
      set temp;
      by ID role notsorted;

      _start = min(start, _start);
      _end   = max(end, _end);
      _hours = sum(hours, _hours);

   end;

   start = _start;
   end   = _end;
   hours = _hours;

run;
```

**Result:**

```
ID  Start      End        Role   Hours
1   01JAN2013  30APR2013  53100  300.00 
1   01MAY2013  31DEC2013  50100  3.00 
1   01JAN2014  31MAR2015  59100  60.00 
1   01APR2015  01MAY2015  58100  0.00 
1   02MAY2015  30SEP2016  51100  101.00 
1   01OCT2016  31DEC2016  52100  0.00 
2   01JAN2013  30NOV2014  56100  72.00 
2   01DEC2014  31DEC2014  58100  0.00 
2   01JAN2015  01APR2015  55101  54.00 
2   01MAY2015  01JUN2015  56101  0.00 
2   01JUL2015  31DEC2015  56100  0.00 
2   01JAN2016  31DEC2015  56101  98.00 
3   01JAN2013  31DEC2014  52100  124.34 
3   01JAN2015  31DEC2015  55107  8.00 
3   01JAN2016  31DEC2016  50115  9.00 
4   01JAN2014  31JUL2014  51100  300.00 
4   01AUG2014  31DEC2015  50100  159.00 
4   01JAN2016  31JAN2016  51101  7.00 
4   01FEB2016  31DEC2016  51106  234.00
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me start by saying that November only has 30 days.

Next time, please try to provide the tables in a SAS-friendly format

```
data year_2013;
infile datalines delimiter='|';
input id $ start : date9. end : date9. role $ hours 8.;
format start date9. end date9.;
datalines;
0001|01JAN2013|30APR2013|53100|300
0001|01MAY2013|31DEC2013|50100|3
0002|01JAN2013|31DEC2013|56100|60
0003|01JAN2013|31DEC2013|52100|123
;

data year_2014;
infile datalines delimiter='|';
input id $ start : date9. end : date9. role $ hours 8.;
format start date9. end date9.;
datalines;
0001|01JAN2014|31DEC2014|59100|56
0002|01JAN2014|30NOV2014|56100|12
0002|01DEC2014|31DEC2014|58100|0
0003|01JAN2014|31DEC2014|52100|1.34
0004|01JAN2014|31JUL2014|51100|300
0004|01AUG2014|31DEC2014|50100|90
;

data year_2015;
infile datalines delimiter='|';
input id $ start : date9. end : date9. role $ hours 8.;
format start date9. end date9.;
datalines;
0001|01JAN2015|31MAR2015|59100|4
0001|01APR2015|01MAY2015|58100|0
0001|02MAY2015|31DEC2015|51100|34
0002|01JAN2015|01APR2015|55101|54
0002|01MAY2015|01JUN2015|56101|0
0002|01JUL2015|31DEC2015|56100|0
0003|01JAN2015|31DEC2015|55107|8
0004|01JAN2015|31DEC2015|50100|69
;

data year_2016;
infile datalines delimiter='|';
input id $ start : date9. end : date9. role $ hours 8.;
format start date9. end date9.;
datalines;
0001|01JAN2016|30SEP2016|51100|67
0001|01OCT2016|31DEC2016|52100|0
0002|01JAN2016|31DEC2015|56101|98
0003|01JAN2016|31DEC2016|50115|9
0004|01JAN2016|31JAN2016|51101|7
0004|01FEB2016|31DEC2016|51106|234
;
```

I think the below should do the trick. Basically, it computes groups and finally collapse the observations by summing the hours for each group.

```
data have;
    set year_2013 year_2014 year_2015 year_2016;
run;

proc sort data=have;
    by id role descending start;
run;

data stage1;
    set have;
    retain group 0;
    format lag_start date9.;
    by id role start notsorted;

    if first.id then
        lag_start = .;
    else lag_start=lag(start);

    if first.id then
        group+1;
    else if lag_start-1 ne end or first.role then
        group+1;
run;

data want(drop=hours group lag_start);
    set stage1;
    by group;

    if first.group then
        tot=0;
    tot + hours;

    if last.group then
        output;
    rename tot = hours;
run;

proc sort data=want;
    by id start role;
run;
```

Results:

```
 id     start     end     role hours
0001 01JAN2013 30APR2013 53100 300
0001 01MAY2013 31DEC2013 50100 3
0001 01JAN2014 31DEC2014 59100 60
0001 01APR2015 01MAY2015 58100 0
0001 02MAY2015 31DEC2015 51100 101
0001 01OCT2016 31DEC2016 52100 0
0002 01JAN2013 31DEC2013 56100 72
0002 01DEC2014 31DEC2014 58100 0
0002 01JAN2015 01APR2015 55101 54
0002 01MAY2015 01JUN2015 56101 0
0002 01JUL2015 31DEC2015 56100 0
0002 01JAN2016 31DEC2015 56101 98
0003 01JAN2013 31DEC2013 52100 124.34
0003 01JAN2015 31DEC2015 55107 8
0003 01JAN2016 31DEC2016 50115 9
0004 01JAN2014 31JUL2014 51100 300
0004 01AUG2014 31DEC2014 50100 159
0004 01JAN2016 31JAN2016 51101 7
0004 01FEB2016 31DEC2016 51106 234
```